# About the definition of "differential privacy" in communication complexity

Tags: complexity-theory, terminology, cryptography, communication-complexity, differential-privacy

In the context of communication complexity I see a definition of differential privacy which isn't totally clear to me as to why it makes sense.

So the two parties $A$ and $B$ draw two strings $X$ and $Y$ from the set $S^n$ where $S$ is some finite set. Let $P$ be the protocol. Now if $z_1 = (X_1,Y_1)$ and $z_2 = (X_2,Y_2)$ are two instances drawn with a probability distribution $\mu$ over the set $S^n \times S^n$ then the protocol $P$ is called "$\epsilon$-differentially private" if the following holds:

$$e^{-2 \epsilon n}  \leq  \Pr[P(z_1) = p]  /  \Pr[P(z_2) = p]   \leq e^{2 \epsilon n}$$

- Now why does this make sense? What's the intuition?
- How is this related to the bounded derivative definition?

Comment: Where have you seen this definition? It doesn't make much sense, though it is implied by the usual definition (but seems much weaker).

Comment: "The Limits of two-party differential privacy" by Toniann, Vadan, Reingold, Talwar, Mironov, McGregor

Comment: @YuvalFilmus It would be great if you could kindly explain why this definition makes sense and what is the idea it is trying to capture.

Comment: I can't find this definition there. Instead, they have the usual definition of differential privacy. On page 16 in the version https://people.cs.umass.edu/~mcgregor/papers/11-2pdp.pdf I see that they are *deriving* your condition as a consequence of differential privacy.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Isn't the last but one equation on page 16 the definition of an "$\epsilon$-differentially private" protocol? (the first equation below theorem 4.9) ? Or is this derived from some other definition which is more fundamental? It would be great if you could help piece this out!

Comment: Differential privacy is defined on page 4 (Definition 2.1). Take it as an exercise to deduce your condition from that definition.

Comment: Seems like I am missing a lot of links here! So what is the "mechanism" and the Hamming weight adjacency in a communication protocol? This is precisely what I was asking in the question that in a communication protocol what can at all be differential private!

Comment: @YuvalFilmus My feeling is that definition 2.3 is a "new" definition of differential-privacy when applied to communication protocols and probably its not a good idea to use 2.1 in this context. May be you can see this question of mine : http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/44176/how-is-a-communication-protocol-a-mechanism

Comment: It's an excellent idea to use Definition 2.1. Definition 2.3 is just an elaboration of Definition 2.1, explaining what gets into $p$, the output of the protocol (it's not only the transcript!).

Answer (score 2):

Your definition is wrong. The correct definition is as follows. A protocol $P$ is *$\epsilon$-differentially private* (for $\epsilon > 0$) if for any two inputs $Z_1,Z_2$ differing in a single coordinates and any $p$,
$$
e^{-\epsilon} \leq \frac{\Pr[P(Z_1) = p]}{\Pr[P(Z_2) = p]} \leq e^\epsilon.
$$
For small $\epsilon>0$, $e^\epsilon \approx 1 + \epsilon$, and $e^{-\epsilon} \approx 1 - \epsilon$; the quantity $e^\epsilon$ is easier to work with compared to $1+\epsilon$, since $e^{\epsilon_1} e^{\epsilon_2} = e^{\epsilon_1+\epsilon_2}$, whereas $(1+\epsilon_1)(1+\epsilon_2) \approx 1 + \epsilon_1 + \epsilon_2$ holds only approximately.

Another small note: the upper bound implies the lower bound and vice versa.

The definition implies that for any two inputs $Z_1,Z_2$ that differ in at most $d$ places,
$$
e^{-\epsilon d} \leq \frac{\Pr[P(Z_1) = p]}{\Pr[P(Z_2) = p]} \leq e^{\epsilon d}.
$$
In particular, if the inputs have length $m$, then for *any* $Z_1,Z_2$ we have
$$
e^{-\epsilon m} \leq \frac{\Pr[P(Z_1) = p]}{\Pr[P(Z_2) = p]} \leq e^{\epsilon m}.
$$
In your case $m = 2n$.